# Jquery-ui Draggable won't change top position to negative of init position

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I been using Jquery-ui draggable to drag a couple of divs around to get a new position for them,
but i have a problem.

when i init the side i give the div a position absolute, and set it's left and top position, to make the div stand the right way, i wrap them inside a div container called 'Device Preview' and then use this as the containment which works fine, for the first div, the second div, which is placed under the first div, won't go up from its initial position. And i'm at a lost.

So i created this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb6wsrx0/), to show how my code cracks up,

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="DevicePreview" style="min-height:200px;" cg-busy="loader">
                        <div style="position:relative;" class="draggableObj">
                            <div style="position:absolute;">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows btn-success" style="padding:2px; border-radius:15%;cursor:move" ></i>move It</h3>
                                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div style="position:relative" class="draggableObj">
                            <div style="position:absolute; top:80px">
                                <h3><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows btn-success" style="padding:2px; border-radius:15%;cursor:move" ></i>move It</h3>
                                <input class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS

```
$( ".draggableObj" ).draggable({
  containment: "#DevicePreview"
});
```

and as i said, my problem is that i can't get the div at the bottom, to switch places with then one at the top.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i found out that my problem was that i tried to attach draggable on a class which then selected more than one element.

the result was that i could only catch the last element attached to the draggable area, everyone but the last, also created its own containment.

The solution was to create it on a unique Id base element instead, created by som jquery, an then it work.